# Slack API - posting thread replies or emoji reactions in a Slack Connect channel

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a slack bot that works fine across several channels, posting:

- New messages
- Replies to existing messages (using `thread_ts`)
- Emoji reactions on messages

I recently added it to a channel that uses Slack Connect; the channel is owned by our org, but has an external user. It is not a private channel (though our bot works in both private and public channels without Slack connect).

What I find is that the bot is still able to post new messages, but cannot reply to existing ones and cannot put emoji reactions on posts.

I can't find anything in the slack API docs or list of permissions that implies things are different when using Slack Connect, is this a known limitation?

The full response I get on attempt to add a reaction is:

```
{'ok': False, 'error': 'invalid_arguments', 'response_metadata': {'messages': ['[ERROR] must provide a string [json-pointer:/channel]']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out our issue was with the implicit limit of 100 entries in `conversations.list`.

While the initial channel post takes a channel name as an arg, you have to look up channel ID to post threaded responses or reactions. We're using `conversations.list` to look up channel ID by channel name, and our slack connect channel just happened to be the 101st channel in the org.